# viewer for X.509 certificate

Tags: ssl, certificates

Previously X.509 certificates would open properly. I do not know what changed but currently they are opening as text files and shown in `gedit`. How can I revert to the original behaviour?

Edit: I was asked for more information. Previously the file opened to display human readable information about the certificate. When it opens as a text file in `gedit` there are only hexadecimal numbers between a header and footer.

Comment: What does "open properly" mean?

Comment: Open and display human readable information such as the expiry date and name of domain, etc.  Opening it as a text file just shows hex.

Comment: on my 16.04 xubuntu based system, certificates are shown using `/usr/bin/gcr-viewer` (from the gcr packages). Perhaps you could re-associate the certificates with this viewer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Nautilus right click the .crt (certificate file) and select `Properties` and click the `Open With tab`. Click the `Reset` button.

The application used to view it will be reset to what Nautilus calls "View file".

Comment: Thanks, I changed open with application to text and looking for a way to revert back that change